# How to show the forms field so user can fill

Tags: django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to create a form where user can create a team. I did the view, the model and the form, But, somehow the template return with only a submit button and I don't know how to solve it. Any help is of great help, thanks.
Here is the view:

```
def team_create_view(request):
  title = 'Create'
  form = TeamCreateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
  coach = get_coach(request.user)
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
      form.instance.coach = coach
      form.save()
      return redirect(reverse("club", kwargs={ 'id': form.instance.id }))
      context = {
        'title': title,
        'form': form
      }
      return render(request, "team_create.html", context)
```

Now the form:

```
class TeamCreateForm(forms.Form):
  form = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

  class Meta:
    model = Team
    fields  = ('form', 'name', 'logo', 'birth', 'coach', 'players')
```

The model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  logo = models.ImageField(default="", blank=True, null=True)
  birth = models.DateField(default="", blank=True, null=True)
  coach = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="", blank=True, null=True)
  players = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='players')
      
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

And finally the form:

Comment: I edited this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You form render is written in inside the POST method condition. So in GET method does not render.Please try this.

**First Method**

Here we just change `render` code to outside of `POST` method checking `if` condition.

```
def team_create_view(request):
    title = 'Create'
    form = TeamCreateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    coach = get_coach(request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.coach = coach
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("club", kwargs={'id': form.instance.id }))
    context = {'title': title,'form': form}
    return render(request, "team_create.html", context)
```

**Second Method**

Here we check if `GET` method.

```
def team_create_view(request):
    title = 'Create'
    form = TeamCreateForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    coach = get_coach(request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.coach = coach
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("club", kwargs={'id': form.instance.id }))
    elif request.method == "GET":
       context = {'title': title,'form': form}
    return render(request, "team_create.html", context)
```

Comment: It worked as you suggest. But, another problem just occur. The form render a textarea instead of the fields I defined in the team models.